# How to pad a number with zeros to a specific length in tcl?

Tags: numbers, append, tcl

I need to pad a number with a specific length (say 8) where the input number could be of any length.

Example: If the input number is 123456, I want to pad it as 12345600

If I knew that all input numbers would be of the same length (say 6), I would have done something like

```
[format "$input_num%02d" 0]
```

But since the input number can be of varied length, how do I achieve this?
Obviously the below didn't work:

```
set cur_length [expr[llength[split $input_num ""]]
set padding [expr 8 - $cur_length]
set padded_num [format "$input_num%${padding}d" 0]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really simple, actually:

```
format %-08s $input_num
```

A number is also a string, so it can be left-justified like a string.

Documentation: [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm)

Comment: And what if I want to prepend it in the front rather than appending in the end? Eg: to get 00123456?

Comment: @Tcl_newbie: just remove the dash.

Comment: And if you don't want to hard-code "8", then `set width 10; format {%-0*s} $width $input_num` -- using `*` means you put the field width as an argument.